# Как при наведении мыши на 3D объект сделать подсказку?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

Здравствуйте. Как при наведении мыши на 3D объект MeshGeometry3D сделать подсказку?

```
   <Model3DGroup x:Name="Sp02">
        <GeometryModel3D x:Name="Spr01">
            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="Sp01" Positions="..." />
            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                <MaterialGroup x:Name="mG1">
                    <DiffuseMaterial>
                        <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="Material__83_Diffuse_Spr01" Color="#A8A8A8" Opacity="1" />
                        </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                    </DiffuseMaterial>
                </MaterialGroup>
            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
            <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                <MaterialGroup>
                    <DiffuseMaterial>
                        <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="Material__83_Diffuse_Spr01_Back" Color="#A8A8A8" Opacity="1" />
                        </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                    </DiffuseMaterial>
                </MaterialGroup>
            </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
        </GeometryModel3D>
    </Model3DGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку MeshGeometry3D - это не Control, впрямую использовать ToolTip не получается. Вместо этого можно отслеживать события MouseEnter and MouseLeave и в них отображать ToolTip.

```
private void X_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = e.GetPosition(someObject);

    tooltip.Show("Это подсказка", someObject, p);
}

private void X_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    tooltip.Hide(someObject);
}
```

Comment: Каким образом можно отследить эти события ведь у MeshGeometry3D нет событий MouseEnter и MouseLeave?

Comment: И методы Show и Hide у ToolTip отсутвуют в WPF. Какие методы надо использовать вместо них?